# Can't initialize an array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an array of pointers to a structure called "table" (the structure is called Node).

I declare the array as so in the class:

```
Node * table;
```

Then, in another method, I initalize the table:

```
this->table = new Node [this->length];
```

And everything works fine. this->length is a valid entry, this->table is pointing to the right array, and etc. However, then I try to change the value of the elements:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this->length; i++) {
    this->table[i] = new Node;
}
```

Or even

```
for(int i = 0; i < this->length; i++) {
    this->table[i] = 0;
}
```

And everything starts bugging out. Why can't I set these pointers to anything?

This is the error I get:[image]

(Where line 15 is the line of "this->table[i] = new Node;").

I hate to post long segments of code, so here's a shortened version of the code itself:

```
template <class T, class S>
class HashMap {
    public:
        HashMap();
    private:
        struct Node;
        Node * table;
        static const unsigned length = 100;
};

template <class T, class S>
HashMap<T, S>::HashMap() {
    this->table = new Node [HashMap::length];
    for(int i = 0; i < HashMap::length; i++) {
        this->table[i] = new Node;
    }
}

template <class T, class S>
struct HashMap<T, S>::Node {
    T value;
    S key;
    Node * next;
};
```

No research I'm doing is telling me what the error is; any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an array of pointers.  You have an array of Nodes.  Apparently, what you want is something like this:

```
Node ** table;
...
this->table = new Node*[this->length];
```

Or maybe you don't actually need an array of pointers, but simply an array of nodes.  In that case, no extra initialization is needed beyond:

```
this->table = new Node[this->length];
```

Beyond that, unless this is a learning exercise, take a look at the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page), which has [dynamic arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [hash maps](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) all ready for you.

Answer (score 1):

`table` is not an array of pointers. It's an array of `Node`s (or rather, it points to an array of `Node`s). The type of `table` is `Node*`; the type of `table[i]` is `Node`, not `Node*`.

If you actually do want an array of pointers, then you need

```
Node** table;
table = new Node*[length];
```

Or better still, something like

```
vector<unique_ptr<Node>> table;
table.resize(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have declared an array of pointers.
Node *table(point to a node)
Node **table(point to an array Nodes)

```
Node** table;
table =new Node*[this->length];
for(int i=0;i<this->length;i++)
{
   table[i]=new Node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this->table = new Node [HashMap::length];
```

`this->table` is of type `Node*` and new Node [HashMap::length] also returns a Node* , i.e. an array of Node of lenght `HashMap::length` is created and the array address is stored in `this->table` pointer.

```
this->table[i] = new Node;
```

As an example, we can define:

```
int* arr = new int[10];
```

Here arr is of type int* but `arr[0]` will be of type int.

similarly, `this->table[i]` is of type Node and new Node returns Node*. Hence incompatible types. Correct line would be

```
this->table[i] = *new Node;
```

But, this line is unnecessary as the array of Nodes is already created and the memory is allocated. Using this line in the code will lead to a memory leak.